# When binding data in D3, what does the index represent?

Tags: d3.js, data-binding

I was a bit surprised when I saw the value of the index passed to the data binding function of step 3 in the following example:

1) Create two wrapper divs with a data array bound to each

2) Create two "sub-divs" within each of the wrappers, with an array bound to each

3) Append p elements to each "sub-div"

Because of the way the elements are nested, I expected to see indexes of 0,1 passed to the data binding function in step 3. Instead, I see indexes of 0,1,2,3.

```js
var data = d3.select("#data");
var idx = d3.select("#indexes");

//---- STEP 1
//create two divs with [1, 4] and [7, 10] bound
var dbox = data.selectAll("tbody").data([[1, 4], [7, 10]]);
dbox.enter().append("div").text(function(d,i){return "Group " + i });
dbox.exit().remove();
dbox.style({"clear":"both","padding":"5px","border":"1px solid #dddddd","overflow":"hidden","margin-bottom":"10px"});

//---- STEP 2
//create sub-divs
var tr = dbox.selectAll("div").data(function(d,i){
  return d.map(function(d,i,a){ return [d, d+1, d+2]; }); //return an array of arrays [[x,y,z], [a,b,c]]
});
tr.enter().append("div").text(function(d,i){return "Index " + i});
tr.exit().remove();
tr.style({"clear":"both","overflow":"hidden","padding":"2px","border":"1px dotted #dddddd","margin-top":"5px"});

//---- STEP 3
//add text (and record indexes in the "INDEXES" section)
//since the tr selection is grouped--with two "tr" divs per "dbox", I expected to see indexes of 0,1 only, instead I see 0, 1, 2, 3.
var td = tr.selectAll("p").data(function(d,i){
  idx.append("p").text(i); //track the indexes
  return d;
})
td.enter().append("p");
td.exit().remove();
td.text(function(d,i){return d}).style({});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
  
</div>

<div id="indexes" style="clear:both;padding-top:20px;">
  <p>INDEXES</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No, the indices refer to the parent groups (i.e. are "global" in your case). I guess it makes more sense because there's only one call to `.data()`.

Comment: Aren't the parent groups the members of the "tr" selection (in the above example)? If so, I'd still expect indexes of 0,1. I updated the example to illustrate.

Comment: Well there are 2*2 parent groups, so altogether 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectAll` simply promotes all of the elements in the selection to parent nodes (ignoring group structure) and applies the provided selector to each of the new parent nodes in turn to form new groups on them.  After this, there is no references in the selection to the previous parent nodes, that state is lost.

`tr.selectAll("p")` promotes all of the divs in `tr` (2x2 = 4 of them) to parent nodes and forms an enter selection based on the data bound to them.  So there a 4 groups (one for each div in `tr`) with 3 members each (the first dimension of the data bound on the parent divs is of length 3).  References to the previous parent nodes are discarded.

if *`values`* in `selection.data(`*`values`*`)` is a function, then it's `d` argument is the data bound on the group parent and `i` is the group index.

If *`values`* is not a function then the same data is bound to each group.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here is that when operating on selections using methods like .attr() or .style(), the index passed to a function argument represents the index of the element within its parent group.

When binding data using the .data() method, the index passed to a function argument represents the index of the parent element. This is what Lars is getting at in his comments.

I suppose this makes sense because D3 selections use a fixed two-level hierarchy (though it sounds like this may [change in the future](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md)). So when you bind new data, the hierarchy of the selection changes. I.e. the parent elements are no longer nested in the selection.

Here's a clarifying example:

```js
var L1 = d3.select("div#boxes");
L1.append("p").text("Level 1");

var L2 = L1.selectAll("div").data([1,2]);
L2.enter().append("div");

L2.append("p").text(function(d,i){return "Level 2"})

var L3 = L2.selectAll("div").data(function(d,i){
    return [i,i];
});
L3.enter().append("div");
L3.append("p").text(function(d,i){return "Level 3 - Index during data binding: "+d+". Index after appended: "+i+"." })

var L4 = L3.selectAll("div").data(function(d,i){
    return [i,i];
});
L4.enter().append("div");
L4.append("p").text(function(d,i){return "Level 4 - Index during data binding: " +d+". Index after appended: "+i+"."})
```

```css
div{
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid #555555;
}

p{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}

#indexes p{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
</div>
```

Comment: You said "When binding data using the .data() method, the index passed to a function argument represents the index of the parent element *within the entire DOM*."   Not sure what you mean there, d3 is only aware of what's in the selection, it's not aware of the entire DOM.

Comment: True, I was thinking in terms of my example which traversed the full extent of the DOM. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I still have some problems with your prose... 1) `selection.data()` can receive two arguments which are function: _`values`_ and _`key`_ so it's not absolutely clear which function argument you are talking about. 2) "the index passed to a function argument represents the index of the parent element." I suggest that it's difficult to explain this without directly mentioning the d3 _group_ concept.  "The index passed to the _value_  argument function is the group index" would be clearer. There are other indecis that could be applied to the parent element, e.g. It's DOM context.